# how to schedule a task, pop up an alert and go to phone home screen?

Tags: android, timer, android-alertdialog

I want to schedule a task, rise an alert box to notify the user then "quit" my application and automatically go to the phone home screen. But I dont know how to do that. I tried following code but it's not working. May someone help me? Thanks.

```
timer.schedule(task, calendar.getTime());

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);                      

f.alert(context, title, msg + "Task scheduled for: " calendar.getTime());
```

The alert method is one I wrote from alertDialog and it's working fine. But no alert is shown when I execute the code. Maybe I'm using the wrong context?

[EDIT]
There is the whole story. I've two scenarios. I allow the user to run the task now or later. If he choose "Now", he get a screen with the progress bar telling him to wait until task is done. Else if he choose "Later" I want to schedule the task with `Timer`, show an alert or a toast, then go to the home screen. The task waiting background to be executed. So, to skip the progress bar (waiting for right time to run the task), I want to "quit" the application then go to the phone home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the alert before you start the home activity -- your activity is paused immediately when you call `startActivity`. You probably want to use a `Toast` and not an `AlertDialog` there since you almost certainly don't need any user input at this point; if you are dead set on using an `AlertDialog` you'll have to either hold off switching to the home activity until they click "OK" on it, or start a new activity with a transparent theme to house the dialog appearing over the home screen.

Comment: In fact, There is a confirm button I press to set the schedule. After confirm, I have a screen with a progress bar. Telling me, the task is running "Please wait".  When I do that, I get stuck on the progress bar I've made.

Comment: My first post is edited, I added clarifications about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, now it's a very different question -- now you're asking about why your task doesn't dismiss your dialog when it finishes running, but you haven't posted any of that code. I'd pose that as a new question here, and post the relevant code and tasks.

Comment: No, that's the same question. I've already tried the timer and it's working fine. The intent to go to home screen also work fine. Now I just want to show an alert or a Toast before or after going to home screen.

Comment: OK - then like I said, just make sure to create and `.show()` your toast *before* you actually start the home activity. Once you start another activity, your activity is paused and can't execute any UI code.